# Windows Console API Mouse Event Just Goes To Select Mode

Tags: c++, windows, console

I am using Windows 10, while key events work okay. The problem is with mouse events clicking in the console sort of just automatically assumes I am trying to select and thus goes into select mode. I am not sure if there is something in the API to turn this off.

Update: Anyone who wants to solve this here is  a link to the solution [SOLUTION](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/16988/)

Comment: Just configure the console the way you want it.  Click the system menu (or press Alt+Space) > Properties > Options tab > untick "QuickEdit Mode".  Or use the Get/SetConsoleMode() winapi function to turn off ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT_MODE, but do consider leaving that choice to the user of your program.

Comment: Disabling ~ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT_MODE was not working adding  ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS worked though, thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46567248/how-to-disable-user-selection-in-windows-console This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Mouse selection mode was one of the [console improvement features introduced in Windows 10](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2014/10/07/console-improvements-in-the-windows-10-technical-preview/#AYROJctbLQg4BlSI.97). It can be turned on/off from console parameters. Note that if you want to disable it for your application you can configure console parameters for shortcut.