# How to disable user selection in Windows console

Tags: c++, winapi, console, windows-console

I need to disable user mouse selection in the Windows console. Is it possible and how? I tried the function `SetConsoleMode()` to disable mouse input with it, but it did not work as I expected. Selecting was still possible.

Comment: Is this what you really need, or just what you think is your solution? This really smells like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). And even if it isn't, this setting is at the user's discretion.

Comment: I'm guessing that you're talking about using the mouse for cut-and-copy type operations? I think all you can control with `SetConsoleMode()` is whether mouse events can be read by the program. I don't know if console cut-and-copy is controllable using an API call; even if it is, I suspect it might vary between Windows releases.

Comment: @Ron: That flag controls, whether you get mouse input notifications in the console. It does not change, how the console itself responds to mouse input.

Comment: @IInspectable True. I stand corrected.

Comment: @eryksun Yes it works, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The console's quick-edit mode allows the user to quickly select and copy text using the mouse, without having to first enter mark mode (i.e. <kbd>Ctrl+M</kbd>, or Edit -> Mark on the menu). It's usually convenient to enable quick-edit mode, but it does interfere with getting mouse input. You can disable it using a handle for the console input buffer as follows:

```
DWORD prev_mode;
GetConsoleMode(hInput, &prev_mode); 
SetConsoleMode(hInput, ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS | 
    (prev_mode & ~ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT_MODE));
```

Remember to restore the previous mode at exit.

Comment: This doesn't work on Attached Console. I `  AllocConsole();
  AttachConsole(GetCurrentProcessId());` I want to disable the selection or any input so that no interaction or selection with the console windows is possible.

Comment: @Zingam, it seems like you want to disable all forms of input; use `SetConsoleMode(hInput, ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS)`, which will disable all input modes. FYI, `AllocConsole` allocates and attaches to a console. Don't call `AttachConsole`; the call is probably failing anyway because the process is already attached to a console.

Comment: You have to obtain the handle using CreateFile (CONIN$) as opposed to using GetConsoleWindow - e.g. "HANDLE hInput = CreateFileW(L"CONIN$", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, nullptr, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, nullptr);
"

Comment: @Den-Jason, first try `GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE)`. If that handle cause `GetConsoleMode` to fail with `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE`, then you can fall back on opening "CONIN$". FYI, `GetConsoleWindow` returns the console window handle, if the console has a window, which it may not. A window handle refers to a window object in the window manager, not a file object in the kernel.

Comment: @ErykSun OK, noted.  The use of opening CONIN$ is based on the answer given to the MSDN question "how use the ReadConsole() for read enter key or any key"